# closed integral curves and conservative fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

If a vector field $\vec{E}(\vec{x})$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has no closed integral curves, does this imply that the field is *conservative*, i.e. there is some scalar function $V(\vec{x})$ such that $\vec{E}(\vec{x}) = -\nabla V(\vec{x})$?

Comment: Are you mixing up the concepts of "integral curve which is closed" with "integration along a closed curve"? They are different things.

Comment: Do you consider stationary orbits to be closed?

Comment: I mean "an integral curve which is closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the vector field $\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=\left< 0, 1 + x^2, 0 \right>$. You can check that this has non-zero curl and cannot be a gradient, and has no closed integral curves.